# Mixture / Union of Measures defined on disjoint subsets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-probability

Suppose I have a partition of $\mathbb{R}^N$
$$
\mathbb{R}^N = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{R}} \mathcal{X}_i \qquad \qquad \text{with } \mathcal{X_i} \cap \mathcal{X}_j = \emptyset \text{ if } i \neq j
$$
and that for each value of $i\in\mathbb{R}^N$ I have a measure $\pi_i: \mathcal{X}_i \to [0, +\infty)$. Since all together the measures $\{\pi_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{R}}$ can "measure" the whole of $\mathbb{R}^N$, I would like to gather them together into one measure
$$
\pi: \mathbb{R}^N \to [0, +\infty)
$$
defined as
$$
\pi(A) = \sum_{i\in\mathbb{R}} \pi_i(A \cap \mathcal{X}_i)
$$

> Does this measure $\pi$ have a name?(e.g. mixture/union of measures) Essentially I would like to be able to write something like this $\pi = \bigotimes_{i\in\mathbb{R}} \pi_i$, is this doable?

Comment: I would probably say "disjoint union".  And write $$\bigsqcup_{i \in \mathbb R} \pi_i$$

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you so much! Do you know if there's any literature on these disjoint union measures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about a "sum" over the uncountable index set $\mathbb{R}$. This is problematical. If you think of the plane as the infinite disjoint union of a pencil of parallel lines, you cannot recover the area of a set from the area (measure) of its intersection with each of the lines by summing. You need an integral of some kind to formalize [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle).

I am sure this is discussed in the literature but I don't see immediately how to look up a reference.

**Edit**

Searches for *measurable foliation* and *measurable fibration* lead to some links that may be helpful (and many that are probably more technical that what you need).

Comment: What if those are measures with a density with respect to the N-1 dimensional Hasdorff Measure?

Comment: I don't think that's enough. In the example of a pencil of parallel lines the measure on each line _is_ Lebesgue measure there. What you need is a measure on the set of indexed sets. For a pencil of parallel lines you could use Lebesgue measure on an orthogonal transversal. That is Cavalieri's principle.